# Set timeout on a TypedQuery with JPA2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I would like to set a timeout on a javax.persistence.TypedQuery.

I've found this easy method :

```
TypedQuery<Foo> query = ... ;
query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 1000);
query.getReturnList();
```

**But it seems that does not work, it's just ignored.**

From the **PRO JPA 2** book:

> "Unfortunately, setting a query timeout is not portable behavior. It
>   may not be supported by all database platforms nor is it a requirement
>   to be supported by all persistence providers. Therefore, applications
>   that want to enable query timeouts must be prepared for three
>   scenarios.
>
> The first is that the property is silently ignored and has no effect.
>
> The second is that the property is enabled and any select, update, or
>   delete operation that runs longer than the specified timeout value is
>   aborted, and a QueryTimeoutException is thrown. This exception may be
>   handled and will not cause any active transaction to be marked for
>   rollback.
>
> The third scenario is that the property is enabled, but in doing so
>   the database forces a transaction rollback when the timeout is
>   exceeded. In this case, a PersistenceException will be thrown and the
>   transaction marked for rollback. In general, if enabled the
>   application should be written to handle the QueryTimeoutException, but
>   should not fail if the timeout is exceeded and the exception is not
>   thrown."

Does anyone knows any other method to specify a timeout on a TypedQuery?

Or how can I make this "hint" working?

Thanks

**EDIT: Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 and PostgreSql 9.2.9 
with JPA 2.1 / Hibernate**

Comment: A simple search for Postgresql shows that they may not have implemented JDBC setTimeout in its JDBC driver, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175173/jdbc-postgres-query-with-a-timeout  with a workaround if you can get hold of the JDBC Connection that Hibernate uses

Comment: Following this report (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4662) Hibernate should support it since version 3.5. Is there an global setting in the persistence.xml.

Comment: Timeout may appear to be ignored if you specify value less than half a second. Although JPA requires timeout in milliseconds it rounded to seconds for the `java.sql.Statement#setQueryTimeout(int seconds)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know its late to reply, but we faced similar problem Oracle 11g, JPA2.0 and this hint wasn't working.

Actually the problem was we were using it as @NamedQuery hint and were calling the function inside @transactional aspect. As @NamedQuery gets loaded and compiled at the time of context load this timeout was overridden by transaction timeout.
You can find more info at http://javadeveloperz0ne.blogspot.in/2015/07/why-jpa-hints-on-namedquery-wont-work.html.

Solution would be fetching named query again and then applying timeout.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("NamedQueryName");
query.setHint("org.hibernate.timeout", "5");
query.getSingleResult();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Hint ignored and its not work please review this question . you should set timeout for  javax.persistence.query.timeout

[Set timeout on EntityManager query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244621/set-timeout-on-entitymanager-query)

Comment: click on the 'Set timeout on EntityManager query"

Comment: put <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="1000"/>
 at your persistence.xml

Comment: I want explictly to use te HINT, as the timeout should be dynamically configurable.